# Exclude values to sum column grouped LinQ

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have my DataTable:

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ CodTipoMoneda ║ idTipoCuenta  ║      Saldo    ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 002           ║            10 ║           854 ║
║ 003           ║            21 ║           500 ║
║ 002           ║            10 ║           500 ║
║ 002           ║            22 ║           680 ║
║ 003           ║            20 ║           130 ║
║ 002           ║            30 ║            10 ║
║ 003           ║            12 ║             2 ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

I need sum the `Saldo` column group by `CodTipoMoneda`, I have this code (*It's Working!*).

```
Dim query = From row In oDT.AsEnumerable()
                Group row By Moneda = New With {
                     Key .CodTipoMoneda = row.Field(Of String)("CodTipoMoneda")
                } Into NameGroup = Group
                Select New With {
                    .TipoMoneda = Moneda.CodTipoMoneda,
                    .Saldo = NameGroup.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Decimal)("Saldo"))
                }
```

but also I would like to add `where` condition to exclude some values from `idTipoCuenta`, for example exclude values `10 and 20` from `idTipoCuenta`.

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ CodTipoMoneda ║ idTipoCuenta  ║      Saldo    ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 002           ║            10 ║           854 ║ (not sum)
║ 003           ║            21 ║           500 ║
║ 002           ║            10 ║           500 ║ (not sum)
║ 002           ║            22 ║           680 ║
║ 003           ║            20 ║           130 ║ (not sum)
║ 002           ║            30 ║            10 ║
║ 003           ║            12 ║             2 ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

I do not know much about, any help is apreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Linq [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) function:

```
Dim query = From row In oDT.AsEnumerable()
            Group row By Moneda = 
            New With 
            {
                Key .CodTipoMoneda = row.Field(Of String)("CodTipoMoneda")
            } Into NameGroup = Group
                   Select New With 
                   {
                         .TipoMoneda = Moneda.CodTipoMoneda,
                         .Saldo = NameGroup.Where(Function(n) n.Field(Of Decimal)("Saldo") <> 10)
                                           .Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Decimal)("Saldo"))
                   }
```

My VB is a little rusty so feel free to adjust accordingly.